# RecycleView Switch will not change value on firebase database when more then one is created

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, uiswitch

When i have mulitple switch on a android recycleview the latest one is giving full functionality.
Meaning if the last one is check or unchecked it changes the value on a firebase database. the others however are will not change the value when checked or unchecked.

I am not sure how to fix this so that any checked or unchecked will change the value of the corresponeding value on the firebase database.

[image: screenshot of recycleview]

this is my code for the switch in my RecyclerViewAdapter.

```
holder.mode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(mode.isChecked()){
            x.blindsMode("auto",x.blindkey);
            data.putString("mode"+x.blindkey,"auto");
            //data.commit();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Blind set to automatic mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else {
            x.blindsMode("man",x.blindkey);
            data.putString("mode"+x.blindkey,"man");
            //data.commit();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Blind set to manual mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        data.commit();
    }

});
```

this is the class where i am setting the value when checked on a firebase database.

```
public class HomeBlinds {
    DatabaseReference ref;
    String blindkey;


    // this will house data on the specific blind.
    public HomeBlinds(String blindkey) {
        this.blindkey = blindkey;
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(blindkey);
    }
    //when this method is called it will set the status node of the blind to open which is then read
    // by the device
    public void openBlinds(){
        ref.child("Status").setValue("open");
    }

    public void closeBlinds(){
        ref.child("Status").setValue("close");
    }

    public void blindsMode(String mode,String bk){

        DatabaseReference r = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(bk);
        r.child("Mode").setValue(mode);
        //ref.child("Mode").setValue(mode);
    }
```

This is what my firebase database looks like, I am changing the Mode key to either auto when the switch is check or man when not checked.

[image]

[image: firebase database]

this is my entire holder class

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    HomeBlinds x = testblinds.get(position);
    String bkey = x.blindkey;

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(bkey);

    ref.child("Location").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String lo = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            holder.loc.setText(context.getString(R.string.loc)+" "+ lo);
            location = lo;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w("Temp error",error.toException());
        }
    });

    ref.child("Temperature").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String t = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            holder.temp.setText(context.getString(R.string.temp)+" "+ t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w("Temp error",error.toException());
        }
    });

    ref.child("Light").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String li  = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            holder.light.setText(context.getString(R.string.li)+" "+ li);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w("Temp error",error.toException());
        }
    });

    //when open button is pressed status value on firebase = open
    holder.open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            x.openBlinds();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),view.getContext().getString(R.string.open)  + location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //when close button is pressed status value on firebase = close
    holder.close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            x.closeBlinds();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), view.getContext().getString(R.string.closing) + location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("saved", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor data = sharedPreferences.edit();
    holder.mode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mode.isChecked()){
                x.blindsMode("auto",x.blindkey);
                data.putString("mode"+x.blindkey,"auto");
                //data.commit();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Blind set to automatic mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else {
                x.blindsMode("man",x.blindkey);
                data.putString("mode"+x.blindkey,"man");
                //data.commit();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Blind set to manual mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            data.commit();
        }

    });

}
```

I have tired assinging the specific blind key to the database reference, but that has not worked.
I have also tired setOnCheckChangedListener for the switch but that has not worked either.

Comment: Are you calling `holder.mode.setOnClickListener(...)` for each view holder in the recycler? Can you show the context of where you call that code?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen